# visualization of correlation between replicates

Tags: r, data-visualization, correlation

To test the quality of the biological replicates by calculating Pearson correlation coefficient for the pairs of biological replicates for each cell-line.

```
A<-data.frame(A1=rnorm(100), A2=rnorm(100),
          A3=rnorm(100), B1=rnorm(100),
          B2=rnorm(100))
```

Some cases of the data have two replicates and others are three and contain no missing values. How to obtain such a plot to compare the replicates?

[image: Quality of replicates]

Comment: How do you determine which columns are supposed to be replicates of each other.  Is it based on column name, or do you have that data explicitly?

Comment: @mrip : It is based on the column names

Comment: The first thing you need to do then is process the column names to find replicates.  Are the column names for replicates identical, or do they have suffixes `1,2,3` as in your example?  Maybe give the first 10 column names or so.

Comment: @ mrip : The column names are suffixed with 1, 2, 3. Let us assume in this case as A1,A2,A3,B1,B2,C1,C2,C3,D1,D2,D3,E1,E2 AND SO ON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possible way.  There's probably a more concise way to do this, though.

First thing, figure out which columns are replicates of which.

```
fullnames<-colnames(A)
basenames<-substr(fullnames,1,nchar(fullnames)-1)
repnum<-as.integer(substr(fullnames,nchar(fullnames),nchar(fullnames)))
```

Now compute the correlation matrix, and extract the data you need:

```
ca<-cor(A)
corMask<-upper.tri(ca) & basenames[col(ca)]==basenames[row(ca)]
corSub<-ca[corMask]
nameSub<-basenames[row(ca)[corMask]]
repnumSub<-apply(cbind(repnum[row(ca[corMask]],repnum[col(ca[corMask]]),1,paste,collapse="-")
```

Then draw the plot:

```
require(ggplot2)
plotdata<-data.frame(name=nameSub,cor=corSub,replicas=repnumSub)
ggplot(plotdata,aes(x=name,y=cor,pch=replicas))+geom_point()
```

Here's what it looks like, with the following sample data set:

```
set.seed(123)
A<-data.frame(A1=rnorm(100), A2=rnorm(100),A3=rnorm(100),
          B1=rnorm(100),B2=rnorm(100),
          C1=rnorm(100),C2=rnorm(100),C3=rnorm(100))
```

[image]

You can then add color or change the plot limits etc. to make it look the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that the better representation would be using a heat map. The heat map visualizes the correlations between replicates. So, replicates from the same batch will show much higher correlation than other cell lines. So, ultimately you will see values close to 1.0 at the diagonal of the cells in your heat map. The heat map also shows the poor correlation between replicates from different cell lines. To perform such drawing function, you can use `heatmap.2` from {gplot} package.